# UV unwrap issue

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am fairly new to blender coming from a 3ds max / Maya background and I'm trying to Unwrap my frog model.

I have made UV seams on edges to split up the UV islands, but when I unwrap it just messes up all the UVs, as shown in the image.

I can still unwrap by view, and relax the UV, but its still causing issues right on the edges.

I used unwrap before and it was working fine, I had to re do my model as the legs weren't animating well, but now its just not working at all.

would it being skinned / animated have anything to do with it? I know your supposed to UV unwrap before you animate, but I noticed with blender when you go into edit mode it resets the model to its original pose, I thought It wouldn't matter if I animated it first and wanted to make sure I didn't have to edit any geometry before I UV unwrapped it again.

Anyone know whats causing this? I am just marking my seams, hitting Ctrl A and then unwrap, but the highlighted square in the image shows what happens if I do it.

[image]

Cheers[image]

Comment: Try to Remove Doubles.

Comment: tried this but nothing :/

Comment: Could you upload blend file (or just troublesome part of it) to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Did you applied any modifiers before uploading this file?

Comment: yes I had a subsurf and armature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your **UV Vertices** are **Pinned**.

[image: pinned]

To **Unpin** select them all - <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Next hover your 3D model and <kbd>U</kbd> > **Unwrap** and lastly (optional) back to **UV Image Editor** and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to **Pack Islands**.

[image: result]

Comment: ah haha, must have pressed a button and pinned them all. cheers man big help

Comment: @Fidrik If I helped consider upvoting and accepting my answer ;)

Comment: done, although im not high enough to upvote yet :')

Comment: good explanations i upvoted you both ;)